# stuck on grub bootloader and cant access windows

Tags: windows-7, debian, grub

OK so I developed a lot of mobile software but have just broken into computers. I installed debian 6 and I put grub in the wrong spot (hd0,2) to be exact. When I boot up to my debian 6 amd64 I get stuck at the debain disclaimer with the username-pc: command line after signing in, and when I reboot and hit windows7  loader it reboots back to the grub loader. I don't have a DVD for my windows and can't get into the debian graphic desktop environment. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair?

Comment: Do I run that as a command?  EDIT: or is there a command to active the desktop environment on debian from the grub loader terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Boot-repair.  Boot-Repair, simple tool to recover access to your Operating Systems.  To get Boot-repair you can download it [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

Once you download the ISO file, go ahead and burn it to a CD, then make sure that your system is set to boot from CD.  Boot from the newly created Boot-repair CD, and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: I can't access anything. In a lack of better computer term its bricked and stuck in grub-loader. Is there anyway to make the debian desktop load from grub?

Comment: When I get into boot-repair all I get is "no default or UI configuration directive found!" Then the "BOOT:" command line.